module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'colormaps'
I am using package WindroseAxes, whose function .bar has a parametere cmap for defining the color map. See  https://windrose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=bar#windrose.WindroseAxes.bar
It says that ' cmap (a cm Colormap instance from matplotlib.cm, optional.) '.
Therefore, I was reading matplotlib document : https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.ColormapRegistry
import matplotlib as mpl
cmap = mpl.colormaps['viridis']

In my code, I was doing cmap = mpl.colormaps['magma']
 ax.bar(wd, ws, normed =True, opening=1, edgecolor='white', bins = speed_bin, cmap = mpl.colormaps['magma'], nsector = 12)
Then, the error comes out:
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'colormaps'.
So, can I ask what should I do to resolve this? Thanks.

Do you perhaps have a file named matplotlib.py laying around?  That would be found by the import before the actual module.

@jasonharper , thanks for your hint. I did import matplotlib.cm as cm at beginning.  It is resolved by ax.bar(wd, ws, normed =True, opening=1, edgecolor='white', bins = speed_bin, cmap = cm.jet, nsector = 12) .

You didn't add fully reproducible code, making it hard to guess what is going wrong.  In theory, cmap=mpl.colormaps['magma'] should work. Nowadays, you can just write cmap='magma'. Also note that jet should be avoided as it shows highlights at the wrong spots.

No need to do import matplotlib as mpl.
Just use those imports in the example.
from windrose import WindroseAxes
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Because cm (color map) is imported, so just use cmap = cm.jet , in .bar
ax.bar(wd, ws, normed =True, opening=1, edgecolor='white', bins = speed_bin, cmap = cm.jet, nsector = 12)


Many roads lead to Rome. cmap='magma' and cmap=plt.get_cmap('magma') are often used in practice. The difference is mostly for historic reasons, as over time easier ways are introduced for such an often-used parameter.  By the way, you should choose between from matplotlib import pyplot as plt and import matplotlib.pyplot as plt. Both ways are equivalent, but you shouldn't use them both in the same code. (And, if you prefer a rainbow-like colormap, cmap='turbo' would be a better choice)
